# Maven release no POM in this directory

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use the `maven-release-plugin 2.3.2` on a multi module POM. (Maven 3.0.4)

`release:prepare` works fine but `release:perform` fails with this error

```
[INFO] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.MissingProjectException: The goal you specified 
requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (...<workspace>/target
/checkout). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory.
```

Now the parent POM lies inside this `<workspace>/` but in the `<workspace>/target/checkout` there is no POM as the `target` directory was created by the plugin. I am assuming there should be a copy of the pom.xml here which should be created by the plugin and that is why the error.

What I am doing wrong ? Directory and POM structure attached. Module 1 and 2 both have respective `pom.xmls` in root.

---

[image: dir structure]

---

I have looked at [maven release plugin, git, and the pom's not at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558785/maven-release-plugin-git-and-the-poms-not-at-the-top)  , [maven generating pom file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704813/maven-generating-pom-file) , [Maven 3.0's "mvn release:perform" doesn't like a pom.xml that isn't in its git repo's root directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694139/maven-3-0s-mvn-releaseperform-doesnt-like-a-pom-xml-that-isnt-in-its-git-r?rq=1) . They don't help as my pom already lies in the repo's (SVN)  root directory and this directory where the plugin is looking for the POM is only temporary, so I cannot/should not hard-code it.

Comment: Can you show the directory layout and where your pom's are located?

Comment: Is the given pom.xml which is located in the root of your multi-module build correctly checked-in in SVN at the same position? Have you started the mvn release:prepare and mvn release.perform from the root of the multi-module build?

Comment: fixed it.. wrong path in the `<scm>` tag in the parent POM.. @khmarbaise your comment got me thinking that the `path in SVN=Jenkins workspace=path in <scm>`  is the only way it can work

Comment: can  you help me out what should be the <scm> path in pom.xml.I have same error and I have already more than 2 days in this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it.. wrong path in the  tag in the parent POM. Comment from khmarbaise got me thinking that the path in SVN=Jenkins workspace=path in  is the only way it can work and thats how it did.

Comment: Hi , what should be the SCM <url>. Is it nexus repository or what exactly that ?

Comment: @JDeveloper its a full path to your source code location including VCS tool name. In SVN it could mean a branch or trunk e.g `<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:file:///D:/subversion_data/repos/my_repo/my-app-example/trunk</developerConnection>
  </scm>` Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-releasing.html) or [here - search for scm](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2008/08/using_the_maven.html)

Comment: Also you can pass these values as `-Dparamaters`. The parameters are `connection , developerConnection and url`. Its good to give all 3, though you can live without the `url`

Comment: What are the odds... I made the exact same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not committed target folder in the project structure, due to which its checking out in that folder, and hence not able to find the pom file.

I faced the similar issue.:)