# How can I build multiple independent Gradle projects from one project?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build

I’m basically just trying to do what’s described in [Maven - How to build multiple Independent Maven projects from one project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10665936/758011). The [accepted answer for that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10666529/758011) describes how to use a Maven POM with `pom` packaging and a list of modules.

I need to do the same thing, but with Gradle. What I actually have is two separate projects which I currently have to `cd` into and build individually, and what I want to have is one directory (project) that contains the two projects and from which I can build them both at once. They’re not interdependent—they just generally will need to be built at the same time. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use (as Luke Daley suggests) Prezi Pride: https://github.com/prezi/pride.

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-build-independent-projects-from-one-parent-directory/10632/2.